# German tax for couples : choosing appropriate tax class

Tags: germany, taxes

I have question on taxation and choosing tax classes. It is already complicated enough and now figure out tax classes for couples seem crazy.

Is there a proper tool to check for appropriate tax class for couples? We both earn have a difference of about 15% in annual salary right now. Some calculators show 4/4 is better while other show 3/5. Right now I am leaning towards 4/4.

Also is it possible to change the tax classes multiple times in middle of the year? I might change my job later this year and would then change the salary difference and hence might need new calculation.

Is there proper tool to do these checks or we have to hire accountant for it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

At the end it does not matter. Tax classes only affect payments you receive every month. After submitting your yearly tax declaration (which you are obliged to do having classes 3/5), your taxes will be recalculated and the resulting income will be the same regardless the tax classes you both have.

Note that it does matter in some cases which tax class you have, for example for calculating of the *Elterngeld* the net monthly income is taken which depends on tax class.